# I keep getting ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended what am i doing wrong

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, oracle21c

CREATE SEQUENCE   "MY_USERS_SEQ" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 361 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL

Comment: Looks like you didn't terminate it with `;` which is required according to the [syntax reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571).

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? Some options are version-specific; `noscale` isn't valid until 18c, for example, and `global` isn't valid until 12c  - and those will cause that error in earlier versions.

Comment: Your code works in Oracle 21 [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f535edfe35af985efd19d9c6754aed9d)

Comment: @AlexPoole My DB's version is `12R2` and even no problem occurs with `noscale`, but hurls that error for version `11g`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - it isn't in the [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571) for 12.2, but maybe that's a doc bug and it was added that release? Hmm, yes, it is in [the new features list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Changes-in-This-Release-for-Oracle-Database-SQL-Language-Reference.html#GUID-F7977934-38CE-45FB-AB55-7F67E7285D0C); and in the `create sequence` text - just not in the diagram *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole@MTO Am using 21c. I dont know what am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe you have some characters in the command that are not displayable in the app that is executing the command. Put newlines at key places and see if the error text points you to the problem.

Comment: Even though you're using 21c, your compatible setting could be much lower.